# How to code a matrix in WinBUGS?

Tags: winbugs, winbugs14

I am trying to code the 2X2 matrix sigma with the 4 elements. Not sure how to code in WINBUGS. My goal is to get the posterior p's, their means and variances and create an ellipse region covered by the two posterior p's. Heres my code below:

```
model{
#likelihood

for(j in 1 : Nf){
p1[j, 1:2 ] ~ dmnorm(gamma[1:2], T[1:2 ,1:2])  
for (i in 1:2){
    logit(p[j,i]) <- p1[j,i]
    Y[j,i] ~ dbin(p[j,i],n) 
     }

 X_mu[j,1]<-p[j,1]-mean(p[,1])
 X_mu[j,2]<-p[j,2]-mean(p[,2])

v1<-sd(p[,1])*sd(p[,1])
v2<-sd(p[,2])*sd(p[,2])
v12<-(inprod(X_mu[j,1],X_mu[j,2]))/(sd(p[,1])*sd(p[,2]))

sigma[1,1]<-v1
sigma[1,2]<-v12
sigma[2,1]<-v12
sigma[2,2]<-v2
sigmaInv[1:2, 1:2] <- inverse(sigma[,]) 

T1[j,1]<-inprod(sigmaInv[1,],X_mu[j,1])

T1[j,2]<-inprod(sigmaInv[2,],X_mu[j,2])


ell[j,1]<-inprod(X_mu[j,1],T1[j,1])
ell[j,2]<-inprod(X_mu[j,2],T1[j,2])


}   

#priors
gamma[1:2] ~ dmnorm(mn[1:2],prec[1:2 ,1:2])
expit[1] <- exp(gamma[1])/(1+exp(gamma[1]))
expit[2] <- exp(gamma[2])/(1+exp(gamma[2]))
T[1:2 ,1:2] ~ dwish(R[1:2 ,1:2], 2)
sigma2[1:2, 1:2]  <- inverse(T[,])
rho  <-  sigma2[1,2]/sqrt(sigma2[1,1]*sigma2[2,2])
}


  # Data
 list(Nf =20, mn=c(-0.69, -1.06), n=60,
 prec = structure(.Data = c(.001, 0,
            0, .001),.Dim = c(2, 2)),
 R = structure(.Data = c(.001, 0,
         0, .001),.Dim = c(2, 2)),
 Y= structure(.Data=c(32,13,
         32,12,
         10,4,              
        28,11,                  
        10,5,                  
       25,10,
        4,1,
       16,5,
       28,10,
       21,7,
      19,9,
     18,12,
     31,12,
      13,3,
     10,4,
     18,7,
     3,2,
    27,5,
    8,1,
     8,4),.Dim = c(20, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify each element in turn. You can use the `inverse` function (rather than `solve`) to invert the matrix.

```
model{
  sigma[1,1]<-v1
  sigma[1,2]<-v12
  sigma[2,1]<-v21
  sigma[2,2]<-v2
  sigmaInv[1:2, 1:2] <- inverse(sigma[,])
}
```

Comment: I have modified my code above but keep getting the error    multiple definitions of node ell[1,2]

Comment: Might be `inprod2`... perhaps you want `inprod`, or it might be that you have `ell` in your data? If its the latter, you are defining it twice, hence the error message.

Comment: Please see my code above, I have edited it but now I get the error multiple definitions of node sigmaInv[1,1]

Comment: Have tried several solutions, nothing works. Its multiple definitions of node for ell or sigmaInv. Please help.