# Multiple definitions of node ell[1,2] error in Winbugs

Tags: winbugs, winbugs14

This post is related to my previous post ([How to code a matrix in WinBUGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380299/how-to-code-a-matrix-in-winbugs)). Apologize for a new one as it is a new problem. I get the error `multiple definitions of node ell[1,2]`. I'm not sure how to fix it. Here are the code and the data set for reproducibility.

```
model {
  #likelihood
  for(j in 1 : Nf){
    p1[j, 1:2 ] ~ dmnorm(gamma[1:2], T[1:2 ,1:2])  
    for (i in 1:2){
      logit(p[j,i]) <- p1[j,i]
      Y[j,i] ~ dbin(p[j,i],n) 
    }

    X_mu[j,1]<-p[j,1]-mean(p[,1])
    X_mu[j,2]<-p[j,2]-mean(p[,2])

    v1<-sd(p[,1])*sd(p[,1])
    v2<-sd(p[,2])*sd(p[,2])
    v12<-(inprod(X_mu[j,1],X_mu[j,2]))/(sd(p[,1])*sd(p[,2]))

    sigma[1,1]<-v1
    sigma[1,2]<-v12
    sigma[2,1]<-v12
    sigma[2,2]<-v2
    sigmaInv[1:2, 1:2] <- inverse(sigma[,]) 

    T1[j,1]<-inprod(sigmaInv[1,],X_mu[j,1])

    T1[j,2]<-inprod(sigmaInv[2,],X_mu[j,2])

    ell[j,1]<-inprod(X_mu[j,1],T1[j,1])
    ell[j,2]<-inprod(X_mu[j,2],T1[j,2])

  }   

  #priors
  gamma[1:2] ~ dmnorm(mn[1:2],prec[1:2 ,1:2])
  expit[1] <- exp(gamma[1])/(1+exp(gamma[1]))
  expit[2] <- exp(gamma[2])/(1+exp(gamma[2]))
  T[1:2 ,1:2] ~ dwish(R[1:2 ,1:2], 2)
  sigma2[1:2, 1:2]  <- inverse(T[,])
  rho  <-  sigma2[1,2]/sqrt(sigma2[1,1]*sigma2[2,2])
}

# Data
list(Nf =20, mn=c(-0.69, -1.06), n=60,
     prec = structure(.Data = c(.001, 0, 0, .001),.Dim = c(2, 2)),
     R = structure(.Data = c(.001, 0, 0, .001),.Dim = c(2, 2)),
     Y= structure(.Data=c(32,13,
                          32,12,
                          10,4,              
                          28,11,                  
                          10,5,                  
                          25,10,
                          4,1,
                          16,5,
                          28,10,
                          21,7,
                          19,9,
                          18,12,
                          31,12,
                          13,3,
                          10,4,
                          18,7,
                          3,2,
                          27,5,
                          8,1,
                          8,4),.Dim = c(20, 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `for(j in 1:Nf)` loop you have defined a number of variables (v1, v2, v12, sigma, etc) but these do not have a j index, meaning you are attempting to define them multiple times. Remember BUGS is not a programming language - you cant have a constant like that inside a loop. It is a model specification language which means that every variable can only be specified once. You need to move the variables outside of that loop, or index them.